# How to automatically number each row in a table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Please I want to automatically number each row when data is displayed from the database. Something like this

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

so each row is numbered in ascending order from ***1 to n*** depending on the data available in the database. How do I properly do that. Any Help please am new in laravel

Comment: How about a counter

Comment: Please Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using blade, the laravel's automatically generated $loop variable might help. Like this:

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($items as $item)
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
      <td>{{ $item->first_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $item->last_name }}</td>
      <td>@{{ $item->username }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can find documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable